# Bootstrap col-md-6 added by itself

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can see in the img shown below of my website : http://chorale-universitaire-nancy.com/concerts.php

[image: Img here...]
It's weird as there are 6 rows missing, and no reason why! Can someone help me and tell me what am I missing? The image shows exactly what I mean, and you have the website where you can "Inspect Element". Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not missing, one of your images are higher than another! which is causing the white-space you see, the best way to fix this is to add a `div` with class `row` around each two `col-md-6` `div`s:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed it... thanks! I'll keep in mind to wrap my divs inside a row div next time. Thanks, I REALLY appreciate your help... but I thought that "img-responsive" class makes all images same height, but apparently not...

Comment: @IslamE you're welcome :) usually (but not necessary) we put a `row` class around divs where the sum of `col-md-*` classess is 12.

Comment: Answer is correct, but read about [responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) too.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with CSS floats. To fix it you can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). Just add

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

to the `row` div which is encompassing all the images.